# How do I modify the HTTP headers?

Tags: webserver, page-speed, http-headers, http-server

Google page speed rank demands me to set an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers, by changing the "Expires" and "Cache-Control: max-age".

The site is hosted on a hosting company (not in my garage) on a windows platform.
I tried by uploading a .htaccess file but they have IISPassword program that blocks it.

The question is how do I modify the HTTP headers?

---

```
 
when checking the current header this is what I get:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Location: http://pcgroup.co.il/Default.htm
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 18:38:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 19:16:43 GMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called web.config.txt and then upload it to your server root. Then rename the file, removing `.txt` extension. You will then need to modify the file with the correct code.

Comment: Actually this answer helped realize that I can use the info that @toomanyairmiles wrote without having access to the server settings, only by editing the web.config. Thank you both!

Comment: an example to the web.config:
`<system.webServer><httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>

        <add name="Content-Type" value="; charset=utf-8"/>
        <add name="Expires" value="Mon, 1 Apr 2013 15:30:00 UTC"/>
      </customHeaders>

    </httpProtocol>  </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 4):

A [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file works only on the Apache webserver, you're using Microsoft's IIS Webserver.

See ['Add Expires or Cache Control Header to static content in IIS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865252/add-expires-or-cache-control-header-to-static-content-in-iis)